# Реклама Appodeal в приложении

Tags: java, android

Как вставить рекламу Appodeal? Сможет кто-нибудь помочь или же скиньте хороший тутор, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2):

А чем Вас не устраивает их документация? Как по мне, шикарно сделана:

1. Идете на [страницу выбора платформы](http://www.appodeal.com/sdk/choose_framework)
2. Выбираете `Android`
3. Выбираете нужный тип рекламы и нажимаете `Next`
4. Отключаете лишнее и нажимаете `Next`
5. Выбираете предпочтительный вариант: бОльшая прибыль или лучше отзывы и нажимаете `Next`
6. Указываете, используете или нет `proguard` и нажимаете `Next`
7. Следуете инструкциям.
8. Готово.